# Which tiles came with which Rallyman GT expansion?

Tags: rallyman-gt

I managed to get the tiles from the base game and the different expansions mixed together before noting which tile came from which expansion. Is someone able to provide the range of tile numbers that came with each expansion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base game (32)

- 101 x1
- 102 x1
- 103 x3
- 104 x3
- 105 x2
- 106 x2
- 107 x2
- 108 x1
- 109 x1
- 110 x1
- 111 x2
- 112 x2
- 113 x1
- 114 x1
- 115 x2
- 116 x2
- 117 x2
- 118 x1
- 119 x1
- 120 x1

Championship Pack (12)

- 121 x2
- 122 x1
- 123 x1
- 124 x1
- 125 x1
- 126 x1
- 127 x2
- 128 x1
- 129 x1
- 130 x1

World Tour (12)

- 131 x1
- 132 x1
- 133 x1
- 134 x1
- 135 x1
- 136 x1
- 137 x1
- 138 x2
- 122 x1
- 124 x1
- 125 x1

Team Challenge (12)

- 139 x1
- 140 x1
- 141 x1
- 142 x1
- 143 x1
- 144 x1
- 145 x1
- 146 x1
- 147 x1
- 148 x1
- 149 x1
- 150 x1

KS exclusive (5)

- 151 x1
- 152 x1
- 153 (bridge) x1
- 154 (bridge) x1
- Unnumbered track-less tile